# mfc - MessageBox with rich text

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, richtext

I want to be able to display formatted text inside a message box (like bold text, bullet points, italics, etc.).

I came across [this wonderful article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24/TCX-Message-Box-derived-from-CWnd) but can't seem to get it to work. I am using the demo application at that same link.

Can someone please help me out? I have tried debugging/understanding that code in vain.

Constraints: (not my choice)

- Has to be compatible with Windows XP.
- I'm using Visual C++ 6.

**How it is supposed to display:**

[image: How it is supposed to display]

---

**How it actually displays:**

[image]

Comment: Your article is 14 years old. So, i think you should search for more modern ones, or use custom conrols library - such as BCG Controls Pro.

Comment: I personally would find such a message box very uncool... what an eyesore! Why not use Task Dialogs? They are much more flexible than vanilla message boxes and look nice without being ostentatious.

Comment: @Axilles, Haha true. I would, but my development environment is kinda limited. Free software only (not my choice).

Comment: I edited the question to better reflect my problem. Task Dialogs won't be compatible with XP right?

Comment: @AnishRam Ok, then your choice is limited to "i'm forced to write this damn thing myself". As starting point you can use this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6237/Enhanced-MFC-Message-Boxes It is more modern version of yours. Much more :)

Comment: @Axilles, Definitely. Thanks for that link! Will look into it.

Comment: @AnishRam You are welcome. Good luck in your investigation :)

Comment: I've just tried compiling the CodeProject demo project and it works here, though Visual Studio 2008 is the oldest version I have to hand to build it with.

Looking at the code, I'm not completely convinced by the resizing logic. For that "Sample 6" test, try sticking a break-point after the call to CreateRtfControl() and have a look at the contents of "m_dimMsg" - I get cx=400,cy=188, but possibly you are getting something that isn't right.

Comment: @DavidK, Whoa. That is the problem! `cx` = 1 and `cy` = 3082. Interestingly, when I force set `cx` and `cy` to the values you specified (i.e. 400 and 188 respectively), that sample displays correctly! Could you help me understand what is going on with that resize so I can try and fix it?

Comment: @Anish: The key is that do...while loop at the bottom of CreateRtfControl(). It would be interesting to know what values you get as you go round that loop, and what value does cxLast start off as?

Comment: @DavidK, `cxLast` starts off as 1366. Btw, the author of that code explains his resize algorithm [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/97/Calculating-a-Rich-Edit-Control-Minimum-Size). I didn't understand it too well though.

Comment: @DavidK, On further inspection, inside that `do...while` loop, I find that `m_dimMsg.cy` never changes. Is it supposed to? It is stuck at 3082. I figure that the `RequestResize()` in that `do...while` loop isn't working correctly.

Comment: After further experimentation, I can see similar problems to you if I hack the test project to use RichEdit 1.0, rather than 2.0 (which is the default for Visual Studio 2008). If you look at the comments on that CodeProject article, there's a very interesting one titled "FIX for Windows 2000" - when I add that fix in I get the correct result with RichEdit 1.0 as well. It looks like different versions of RichEdit have different behaviour as to whether the formatting rectangle gets updated when the window is resized. Try adding that "m_edCtrl.SetRect( rc );" call as suggested in that comment.

Comment: @DavidK, Oh wow. That fixed it. Thanks! I should have gone through the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem thanks to the very helpful suggestions of DavidK (see comments on the question). The [FIX for Windows 2000](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24/TCX-Message-Box-derived-from-CWnd#xx516xx) comment fixed this neatly.

Answer (score 3):

Simply create a dialog bow with a RichEdit2 control...

In InitInstance, add the follwing call:

```
// Init RichEdit Library

AfxInitRichEdit2();
```

In your dialog box, create a variable to the RichEdit control and update it as:

```
// Turn Word Wrap on (based on window width)

m_RichEditMsg.SetTargetDevice( NULL, 0);

// Set Base Text

strText = "{\\rtf1\\ansi\\fs20 ";
strText += "{\\colortbl;\\red0\\green0\\blue0;\\red0\\green0\\blue255;\\red0\\green255\\blue255;\\red0\\green255\\blue0;\\red255\\green0\\blue0;}";
    strText += "{\\f1\\cb1\\cf2\\b Main Title} \\par\\par \\fs18 Other text to add {\\b In Bold} no more in bolb ... \\par";
str.Format( "\\par Id: {\\b %s}", m_strProgId);
strText += str;
strText+= "\\par \\par {\\f1 \\b Please Confirm ...} \\par}";

// Update Controls

m_RichEditMsg.SetWindowText( strText);
```

Simply build your own message and you get bold, color, ...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought about this but I didn't like the appearance of this too much. Ideally, I want it to look exactly like a normal message box, but with rich text. This is definitely my fall-back option though.