# Tabular string formatting in Edit Control or MessageBox()

Tags: c++, string, mfc, messagebox

I need to display some data in table format in a read-only multi-line edit control. Since the the edit control's font doesn't have even width for all texts, I could not use this formatting `"%-20s"`, so I chose to use `\t` formatting (see code at the below). But that doesn't help me completely because it displays like in the image.
[image]

I tried using [`GetTextExtentPoint32()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144938(v=vs.85).aspx) API but it could not find the exact width of `\t`. So, how do I align the texts correctly?

```
CString szMsg;
szMsg.Format(_T("%s\t%s\t%s\r\n\r\n%s\t%s\t%s\r\n%s\t%s\t%s\r\n%s\t%s\t%s"),
    _T("ITEM"), _T("VALUE"), _T("STATUS"),
    _T("XXXXXXXX"), _T("1.0001"), _T("PASSED"),
    _T("YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"), _T("-0.0001"), _T("FAILED"),
    _T("ZZZ"), _T("0.0101"), _T("PASSED")
    );
this->GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1)->SetWindowText(szMsg);
```

Note:

1. The strings would be generated during run-time, so it can be of any length.

2. I don't want to use ListCtrl or ListView because I should allow the user to do copy/paste the result.

Comment: I don't think the builtin message box is suitable for that.

Comment: I agree, you would have better results with a listview control in a custom dialog.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mfc - MessageBox with rich text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15402671/mfc-messagebox-with-rich-text)

Comment: Just do a custom a dialog with text control where you set the font to some mono font instead or add some other suitable control. You have too little control over the standard message box.

Comment: @deviantfan I've edited my actual question.

Comment: @WinAppy We understood it before the edit too, so the answer doesn't change: Use a custom dialog.

Comment: @deviantfan The custom dialog or a ListCtrl will not have the ability to do copy/paste, so I have to use Edit control. Anyways check my answer below.

Comment: @WinAppy I don't know what you mean. Of course custom dialogs can support copy/paste.

Comment: @WinAppy Who said you cannot copy/paste in a `CListCtrl` ? You can implement this easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made something like this,

```
#define TAB_WIDTH 56

/*codes skipped*/

CString szItems[4] = { _T("ITEM"), _T("XXXXXXXX"), _T("YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"), _T("ZZZ") };
CString szValues[4] = { _T("VALUE"), _T("1.0010"), _T("-0.0009"), _T("0.1001") };
CString szStatus[4] = { _T("STATUS"), _T("Passed"), _T("Failed"), _T("Passed") };
int nTabs[3][4] = { { 0, 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0, 0 } };

CDC *pDC = this->GetDC();

CFont *pOldFont = pDC->SelectObject(this->GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1)->GetFont());

SIZE sizeText;

for (int ni = 0; ni < 4; ni++)
{
    GetTextExtentPoint32(pDC->GetSafeHdc(), szItems[ni], szItems[ni].GetLength(), &sizeText);
    nTabs[0][ni] = sizeText.cx / TAB_WIDTH;

    GetTextExtentPoint32(pDC->GetSafeHdc(), szValues[ni], szValues[ni].GetLength(), &sizeText);
    nTabs[1][ni] = sizeText.cx / TAB_WIDTH;

    GetTextExtentPoint32(pDC->GetSafeHdc(), szStatus[ni], szStatus[ni].GetLength(), &sizeText);
    nTabs[2][ni] = sizeText.cx / TAB_WIDTH;
}

pDC->SelectObject(pOldFont);

int nBig[3] = { 0, 0, 0 };
nBig[0] = BiggestValue(nTabs[0], 4);
nBig[1] = BiggestValue(nTabs[1], 4);
nBig[2] = BiggestValue(nTabs[2], 4);

CString szDispStr = _T("");

for (int ni = 0; ni < 4; ni++)
{
    szDispStr += szItems[ni];

    for (int nj = nTabs[0][ni]; nj <= nBig[0]; nj++)
        szDispStr += _T("\t");

    szDispStr += szValues[ni];

    for (int nj = nTabs[1][ni]; nj <= nBig[1]; nj++)
        szDispStr += _T("\t");

    szDispStr += szStatus[ni];

    for (int nj = nTabs[2][ni]; nj <= nBig[2]; nj++)
        szDispStr += _T("\t");

    szDispStr += _T("\r\n");

    if (ni == 0)
        szDispStr += _T("\r\n");
}

this->GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1)->SetWindowTextW(szDispStr);
```

and the output is as expected
the edit control displayed
[image]

and the MessageBox() displayed
[image]

here `TAB_WIDTH` is the width of `\t` which I counted the pixels manually. Now I have to find the width of `\t` through code.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using the wrong tool for the job here.

Since you need to present some tabular data to the user, I'd prefer using a control specifically designed for that, like the **list-view control** (in *report* mode). You could just have a dialog-box with a list-view control inside, and use it to present your data to the user.

Since you marked this question using the MFC tag, you can consider the [**`CListCtrl`** class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfshke78.aspx) (or several other enhanced list-view control classes available for free on CodeProject).

If you really want to format some text in tabular data in a *"console-mode" style*, you may want to create a dialog-box with a static text control (or read-only edit control) inside, and set its font to something fixed-width (non-proportional); but I consider the former list-view control approach higher quality.

Comment: @mr-c64 I'm using read-only edit control and I cannot change the font since it is already being used.

Comment: @WinAppy why could you not change the font ?? But anyway ue the listview control as everybody else suggests.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Since the project is legacy I cannot do it. I should use which is already being used. Anyways I've found the solution almost, please check my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to display tabular data in the multi-line edit control is to set the tab stops prior to setting the text. See [EM_SETTABSTOPS message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/bb761663)

This is similar to the now forgotten typewriter tabs, where hitting the TAB key moves caret to the nearest tabstop to the right. You will not be able to right-align numeric data though; for that you'd need to use ListView.

Comment: Even though your answer did not solved my problem, it helped me in figuring out where to set the tabstop which was better. But still I'm trying to solve it completely. Thanks.